# Which is the best way to index through a for loop?

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a product operand on the values inside of a vector. It is a huge mess of code.. I have posted it previously but no one was able to help. I just wanna confirm which is the correct way to do a single part of it. I currently have:

```
vector<double> taylorNumerator;
for(a = 0; a <= (constant); a++) {
    double Number = equation involving a to get numerous values;
    taylorNumerator.push_back(Number);
for(b = 0; b <= (constant); b++) {
    double NewNumber *= taylorNumerator[b];
}
```

This is what I have as a snapshot, it is very short from what I actually have. Someone told me it is better to do vector.at(index) instead. Which is the correct or best way to accomplish this? If you so desire I can paste all of the code, it works but the values I get are wrong.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are trying to do. If `a` is an index on `taylorNumerator`, you can use `operator[]`, `at`, or use a range-based for loop. Please post a proper, complete example.

Comment: Voting to re-open.  The linked question is specifically about `operator[]` and `at()` for vectors.  The question here is what's the best way to go through the elements of a vector, to which the answer is "probably neither `operator[]` nor `at()`."

Comment: There's a close brace missing.  Please put in in the appropriate location.

Answer (score 0):

When possible, you should probably avoid using indexes at all.  Your options are:

- A range-based for loop:

  ```
  for (auto numerator : taylorNumerators) { ... }
  ```
- An iterator-based loop:

  ```
  for (auto it = taylorNumerators.begin(); it != taylorNuemrators.end(); ++it) { ... }
  ```
- A standard algorithm, perhaps with a lambda:

  ```
  #include <algorithm>

  std::for_each(taylorNumerators, [&](double numerator) { ... });
  ```

  In particular, note that some algorithms let you specify a number of iterations, like `std::generate_n`, so you can create exactly *n* items without counting to *n* yourself.

If you *need* the index in the calculation, then it can be appropriate to use a traditional for loop.  You have to watch for a couple pitfalls:  `std::vector<T>::size()` returns a `std::vector<T>::size_type` which is typically identical to `std::size_type`, which is (1) unsigned and (2) quite possibly larger than an `int`.

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != taylorNumerators.size(); ++i) { ... }
```

Your calculations probably deal with `double`s or some numerical type other than `std::size_t`, so you have to consider the best way to convert it.  Many programmers would rely on implicit conversions, but that can be dangerous unless you know the conversion rules very well.  I'd generally start by doing a static cast of the index to the type I actually need.  For example:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != taylorNumerators.size(); ++i) {
  const auto x = static_cast<double>(i);
  /* calculation involving x */
}
```

In C++, it's probably far more common to make sure the index is in range and then use `operator[]` rather than to use `at()`.  Many projects disable exceptions, so the safety guarantee of `at()` wouldn't really be available.  And, if you can check the range once yourself, then it'll be faster to use `operator[]` than to rely on the range-check built into `at()` on each index operation.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine.  Modern compilers can optimize the heck out of the above such that the code is just as fast as the equivalent C code of accessing items direclty.

The only optimization for using `vector` I recommend is to invoke `taylorNumerator.reserve(constant)` to allocate the needed storage upfront instead of the vector resizing itself as new items are added.

About the only worthy optimization after that is to not use vector at all and just use a static array - especially if `constant` is small enough that it doesn't blow up the stack (or binary size if global).

```
double taylorNumerator[constant];
```